# Unable to see minining option in my Ethereum Wallet application

Tags: ethereum, ether

I just installed it and moved to test network but it won't show me the option to mine any ether

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just a Wallet, you can not mine ETH with it.

You can look into other options if you want to mine ETH, for example:

EthMine:(open source software):
https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer

For a beginner is easier to join a mining pool, like:

- Ethpool: https://ethpool.org/
- DwarfPool: https://dwarfpool.com/eth

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing you are using macOS, so you may consider a bit patched version of the ethminer software at

[GitHub - Ethereum miner with OpenCL, CUDA, and stratum support for macOS](https://github.com/sowson/ethminer).

The root cause of this problem is disable "-fcoalesce-templates" attribute for Boost compilation in Hunter for CMake. But, anyway, for me that was only way to use on the latest macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Thanks!